# How to Install "remotely" Binary source from another path location

Tags: centos, rhel, software-installation, path, configure

Suppose this I have a Bynary_Package.tar.gz

When i unzipped this:

```
zxvf Bynary_Package.tar.gz -C /path/dir/
```

Now, I move to

```
cd /path/dir/Bynary_Package/
```

when I list this with `ls -Al` I have the *configure* file

Then one Installation I need to do:

```
./configure ...
make
make install
```

When I perform the `./configure` inside of */path/dir/Bynary_Package/* files are produced in this same folder...

**Question**

How Can I to perform from another location (in example /usr/local/) the installation and producing the result files in the destiny?...

```
# pwd
/usr/local/
#
# /path/dir/Bynary_Package/configure
# /path/dir/Bynary_Package/make
# /path/dir/Bynary_Package/make install
```

Resulting the files in */path/dir/Bynary_Package/* instead of */usr/local/*

**EDIT 1**

Here my example:

```
# mkdir /usr/local/Empty
# mkdir /usr/local/Target
# cd /usr/local/Empty
# pwd
/usr/local/Empty
# ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Jul 13 19:08 .
drwxr-xr-x. 29 root root 4096 Jul 13 19:08 ..
# tar zxvf /home/.../pcre-8.37.tar.gz -C /usr/local/Target/
# /usr/local/Target/pcre-8.37/configure
# pwd
/usr/local/Empty
# ls -al
total 768
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   4096 Jul 13 19:12 .
drwxr-xr-x. 29 root root   4096 Jul 13 19:08 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  14249 Jul 13 19:12 config.h
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  66037 Jul 13 19:12 config.log
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  70546 Jul 13 19:12 config.status
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 Jul 13 19:12 .deps
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    328 Jul 13 19:12 libpcre16.pc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    328 Jul 13 19:12 libpcre32.pc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    269 Jul 13 19:12 libpcrecpp.pc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    323 Jul 13 19:12 libpcre.pc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    311 Jul 13 19:12 libpcreposix.pc
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 344626 Jul 13 19:12 libtool
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 186517 Jul 13 19:12 Makefile
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   2363 Jul 13 19:12 pcre-config
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   6783 Jul 13 19:12 pcrecpparg.h
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  31706 Jul 13 19:12 pcre.h
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   6312 Jul 13 19:12 pcre_stringpiece.h
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root     23 Jul 13 19:12 stamp-h1
#
```

**What I want?**

When I call (`/usr/local/Target/pcre-8.37/configure`) the files created in the */usr/local/Empty* directory must be created in */usr/local/Target/pcre-8.37/* directory instead!!!

**Question 2**

How Can I call `make` and `make install` from */usr/local/Empty* directory and and applied to */usr/local/Target/pcre-8.37/* directory? Like:

```
/usr/local/Target/pcre-8.37/make
/usr/local/Target/pcre-8.37/make install
```

Answer (score 1):

You shall do `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/bynary_package`

Then a `make` with the option required in the Makefile.

Comment: I will wait for something like `/path/dir/Bynary_Package/configure  --prefix=/usr/local/bynary_package` I don't want to do `cd /path/dir/Bynary_Package/`